# Cache item is not getting stored even after inserting using file dependency

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am trying to store a string in cache using Cache.Insert(). When I try to store it using file dependency, after Cache.Insert() my cache value is still null. Please help me out with this problem. Also this code is in Page_load function.
Below is my code for caching:

```
// add 30secs expiration timer
 DateTime time = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(30);

// add file dependency for a file
CacheDependency quesDependency = new CacheDependency(filePath, time);

Cache.Insert("question_of_the_day", html, quesDependency,time, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

// after this step i still get Cache["question_of_the_day"] = null instead of getting that html string.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect absolute expiration time.

```
DateTime.Today - An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Change

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(30);
```

to

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);
```